# Type Mismatch assigning worksheets to array

Tags: vba, excel

Quick Question: I have a function that accepts an array of workbooks and the name of a worksheet to look for.  I'm getting a type mismatch when trying to add each worksheet to the array.  Here's the function:

```
Function AssignSheets(books() As Object, name As String) As Object()
Dim worksheetarray() As Object
ReDim workbookarray(1 To FNum)

For i = LBound(books) To UBound(books)
    Set worksheetarray(i) = workbooks(books(i)).Worksheets(name)
Next i

AssignSheets = worksheetarray

End Function
```

Shouldn't workbooks(books(i)).Worksheets(name) return an object?  Any insight would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What are you passing for books() ?

Comment: How are you calling the function? It's advisable to put `Option Explicit` at the top of your module so it lets you know you haven't declared `Fnum` or `i`.

Comment: Is LBound(books) 1 or 0? The LBound(workbookarray) is 1.

Comment: is "set" necessary in the offending line?

Comment: If you set the books to workbooks then it should be `Set worksheetarray(i) = books(i).Worksheets(name)`. You're treating the elements of books as workbook names, not workbook objects.

Comment: I'm passing an array of workbooks.  They're defined as objects and I've verified that they're being stored as objects.  The lower bound for books() is 1, so no worries there.  

I've added Option Explicit.  FNum and i are defined as Public variables, and they have been successfully defined and are being called.  I'm not sure what you mean by 'How are you calling your function?'  In the main sub I've created an array to store worksheets, with type object, and set it equal to the return of this function, which should be an array of worksheets.  Does that answer your question?

Comment: Jeeped, that did it, thanks!

Comment: Sorry, by _how are you calling your function_ I meant some of the code that's calling it - how are the object and string that `books()` and `name` receive set up.  Jeeped sorted the problem now, so all good.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Jeeped for the comment, he's really the one who answered my question!

First mistake: ReDim workbookarray(1 To FNum) should be ReDim worksheetarray(1 To FNum)

Second Mistake: As Jeeped noted, and I quote:

"If you set the books to workbooks then it should be Set worksheetarray(i) = books(i).Worksheets(name). You're treating the elements of books as workbook names, not workbook objects"

Here's the corrected code:

```
Function AssignSheets(books() As Object, name As String) As Object()
Dim worksheetarray() As Object
ReDim worksheetarray(1 To FNum)

For i = LBound(books) To UBound(books)
    Set worksheetarray(i) = books(i).Worksheets(name)
Next i

AssignSheets = worksheetarray

End Function
```

Thanks for the quick replies everyone!